# Redundant copies of a dictionary as Python list

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to make redundant copies of a dictionary as a list, but update one of the keys. Initially the list has just one item, say, like this:

```
l1 = [{'case':1}]
```

I ran the below loop:

```
for i in range(1,4):
    l1.append(l1[i-1])
    l1[i]['case'] += 1
```

I expected the output to be: `[{'case':1},{'case':2},{'case':3},{'case':4}]`

The actual output is like this: `[{'case':4},{'case':4},{'case':4},{'case':4}]`

How can I get the output as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python keeps a *reference* to the original dict, so if you alter the dict with `l1[i]['case'] += 1` it alters every dict in your list since they are references to the same object (in other words they are the **same** dict).

In order to make them independent you have to call `dict.copy()`, so if you change your code to the following it will work:

```
l1 = [{'case':1}]
for i in range(1,4): 
    l1.append(l1[i-1].copy()) 
    l1[i]["case"] += 1

print(l1)
```